# VLC log files W10 Vetinari

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, logging

I'm using VLC v3.0.18 Vetinari on Windows 10. Previous posts show that I need to go to Tools->Preferences, then "Show Settings". The problem is that this doesn't exist in version v3.0.18. How do I turn it on?

Comment: What you want to set?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I enable logging in VLC v3.0.18 Vetinari

1. Enable "All" in Show Settings
2. Select "Logger" under "Advanced"

[image]

Comment: Thanks I see the problem now, I was using 1280x720 display and the bottom of the dialog didn't show